# Unable to receive UDP packets in ruby

Tags: ruby, udp, windows-firewall

I am attempting to utilize Ruby to implement a simple TIME protocol client. To do this I have attempted to connect to one of the NIST servers using the code below:

```
#socket library is required to use UDPSocket. 
require 'socket' 

s=UDPSocket.new 
s.send("",0,"132.163.96.5",37) # Send empty datagram to the TIME server per the RFC
p resp=s.recv(4) #Receive 4 bytes from the UDP server.
```

Executing the above code results in no response. I have tried changing the TIME server and disabling my windows firewall yet the same problem continues to present. Please assist.

Comment: Works just fine for me but after a few attempts the server stopped responding and I had to pick a different IP. This seems to be due to rate limiting. According to https://tf.nist.gov/tf-cgi/servers.cgi _"All users should ensure that their software NEVER queries a server more frequently than once every 4 seconds. Systems that exceed this rate will be refused service."_

Answer (score 0):

Mysteriously when I send a non-empty udp packet to that TIME server, I get a response so my modified code is:

```
#socket library is required to use UDPSocket. 
require 'socket' 

s=UDPSocket.new 
s.send("non empty message",0,"132.163.96.5",37) # Send a non-empty datagram to the TIME server per the RFC
p resp=s.recv(4) #Receive 4 bytes from the UDP server.
```

This is contrary to [RFC 868](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc868) which states that I need to send an empty datagram to get a response.

Comment: Do you always get a response that way or does the server become unresponsive after a few requests?

Comment: It depends on the request rate. From what I can tell if I send one request per >=4 seconds I always get a response but if I increase the frequency of requests, then the server blocks me to prevent ddos.